# Cant get Bootstrap javascript to work?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am new to rails.

I have this simple code:

```
<h1>Pages#home</h1>
<p>Find <a id="t" rel="tooltip" title="Click me!">me</a> in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>
```

And the pages.js.coffee file:

```
jQuery ->
    $('a#t').tooltip(placement: 'bottom');
```

The tooltip still pops up at the top of the word.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML markup contains an error, look at your links title, it has '>' character which has to be escaped in HTML, use `&gt;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you are using options.
Try this instead. Hope it works

```
$('a#t').tooltip('placement': 'bottom');
```

Comment: make sure you have included the tooltip js file. Then see the error console and tell what is the problem. Also not sure about 'a#t' part try only '#t'

Comment: It may be something wring with the inclusion of the .js files. I use the 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' gem, and did a rails g bootstrap:install to install it in the project. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. That should be an object literal in the `tooltip()` method call.
2. If you've already activated the tooltip on the element, calling the `tooltip()` method again will fail to update the options.

Given that, try something like:

```
if ($('a#t').data('tooltip')) { // check for tooltip data first
  $('a#t').data('tooltip').options.placement = 'bottom';
} else { 
  $('a#t').tooltip({placement: 'bottom'});
}
```

<sub>*Disclaimer: I know neither Rails nor CoffeeScript, but I do know the above code works in JS.*</sub>